# Change two for loops into one LINQ statement

Tags: c#, for-loop

Can't get my head around how to change the below two for loops into one LINQ statement.
Can somebody help me out please.

```
var CleanerAccounts = new List<Account>();
            var array = _context.Accounts.Include(x => x.UserFunctions).ToArray();
            for (int i= 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach(Function f in  array[i].UserFunctions)
                {
                    if(f.UserFunction.Equals("Cleaner"))
                    {
                        CleanerAccounts.Add(array[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Working version for the LINQ statement:

```
var cleanerAccounts = _context.Accounts
                              .Include(x => x.UserFunctions)
                              .Where(account => account.UserFunctions
                                                       .Any(uf => uf.UserFunction.Equals("Cleaner")))
                              .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cleanerAccounts = _context.Accounts
                              .Include(x => x.UserFunctions)
                              .Where(account => account.UserFunctions
                                                       .Any(uf => uf.UserFunction.Equals("Cleaner")))
                              .ToList();
```

Assuming you are good with all of it being done on the database.

If not, add an `.AsEnumerable()` after the `.Include()`, then it will remain in memory.

Comment: I am getting now  `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'WebApi.Entities.Function'.` after adding one bracket before `.ToArray();` to compile

Comment: @rejkid Oh, sorry, I didn't notice your UserFunctions had a UserFunction property. Fixed it.

Comment: Orginal code stored final result as a `List`.

Comment: True, I changed it, although I'd think that the OP got that.

Comment: I fixed it. It is working. I put the working version in my original question.

Answer (score -2):

You can combine the two for loops into one LINQ statement as shown below:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> evenNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: I am sorry to says that I do not see two for loops being converted into one LINQ statement.